# Billboard challenge algorithm

Tags: algorithm, c, interview-questions

[This is a problem from Interview Street in Dynamic Programming section](https://www.interviewstreet.com/challenges/dashboard/#problem/4f2c2e3780aeb).

> **Billboards (20 points)**
>
> ADZEN is a very popular advertising firm in your city. In every road
>   you can see their advertising billboards. Recently they are facing a
>   serious challenge , MG Road the most used and beautiful road in your
>   city has been almost filled by the billboards and this is having a
>   negative effect on the natural view.
>
> On people's demand ADZEN has decided to remove some of the billboards
>   in such a way that there are no more than K billboards standing
>   together in any part of the road.
>
> You may assume the MG Road to be a straight line with N
>   billboards.Initially there is no gap between any two adjecent
>   billboards.
>
> ADZEN's primary income comes from these billboards so the billboard
>   removing process has to be done in such a way that the billboards
>   remaining at end should give maximum possible profit among all
>   possible final configurations.Total profit of a configuration is the
>   sum of the profit values of all billboards present in that
>   configuration.
>
> Given N,K and the profit value of each of the N billboards, output the
>   maximum profit that can be obtained from the remaining billboards
>   under the conditions given.
>
> **Input description**
>
> 1st line contain two space separated integers N and K. Then follow N
>   lines describing the profit value of each billboard i.e ith line
>   contains the profit value of ith billboard.
>
> **Sample Input**
>
> ```
> 6 2 
> 1
> 2
> 3
> 1
> 6
> 10
> ```
>
> **Sample Output**
>
> ```
> 21
> ```
>
> **Explanation**
>
> In given input there are 6 billboards and after the process no more
>   than 2 should be together.
>
> So remove 1st and 4th billboards giving a configuration `_ 2 3 _ 6 10`
>   having a profit of 21. No other configuration has a profit more than
>   21. So the answer is 21.
>
> **Constraints**
>
> ```
> 1 <= N <= 100,000 (10^5)
> 1 <= K <= N
> 0 <= profit value of any billboard <= 2,000,000,000 (2 * 10^9)
> ```

**My solution (psuedocode):**

```
Let Profit[i] denote the Profit from ith billboard.
(i, j) denotes the range of billboards
MaxProfit(i, j) for all (i, j) such that i<=j and i-j+1 <= K is:
    MaxProfit(i, j) = Profit[i] + Profit[i+1] + ... + Profit[j];

For other (i,j) MaxProfit equals,

MaxProfit(i, j)
{
    max = 0;
    for all k such that i<=k<=j // k denotes that, that position has no   billboard
    {
        temp = MaxProfit(i, k-1) + MaxProfit(k+1, j);
        if(temp > max)
        max = temp;
    }
    return max;
}
```

**Code:**

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

long **DP;
long returnValue(long i, long j);
int main()
{
    long N, K;
    scanf("%ld", &N);
    scanf("%ld" ,&K);

    DP = (long**) malloc(sizeof(long *) * N);

    long ARR[N];
    long j, z, i=0;
    for(i=0;i<N;i++)
    {
        DP[i] = (long*)malloc(sizeof(long) * N);
        scanf("%ld", &ARR[i]);
    }


    for(i=0;i<N;i++)
    {
        long sum=0;
        for(j=1;j<=K && (i+j-1)<N;j++)
        {
            sum += ARR[i+j-1];
            DP[i][i+j-1] = sum;
        }
    }

    for(j=K+1;j<=N;j++)
    {
        for(i=0;i<=N-j;i++)
        {
            long max = 0;
            for(z=i;z<=i+j-1;z++)
            {
                long temp = returnValue(i, z-1) +     returnValue(z+1, i+j-1);
                if(temp > max)
                    max= temp;
            }
            DP[i][i+j-1] = max;
        }
    }
    printf("%ld\n", DP[0][N-1]); 
    for(i=0;i<N;i++)
    {
            free(DP[i]);
    }
    free(DP);
}

long returnValue(long i, long j)
{
    if(i<=j)
    {
        //printf("%d\n", DP[i][j]); 
        return DP[i][j];
    }
    else
        return 0;
}
```

My solution is of order O(N<sup>2</sup>). So I get TLE and Segmentation fault for larger N. I have already passed 6/10 test cases. I need to pass remaining 4.

Answer (score 2):

The inputs have to be limited with constraints you have listed, then

- use a TreeSet to store the N objects in it
- remove the K first
- print the Set

few lines in Java (no malloc problem, memory managed by JVM):

- read the first input
- use String.split() the line,
- use Integer.valueOf(String) to convert
- compare N,K and stop if not correct or if negative
- use a `while(<N)` for input,
- test limits of input whith `if` and negative values
- you can use `toString()` to print the Set, but you have to use a
- `foreach` to sum the result
- print result